# Any way to export values for a third party in datadog from a reliable service?

Tags: datadog

Is there any way to do aggregations differently for tags like `host` (where I want `max` or even `latest_value`) than for the tags that are business-meaningful (where I might want `sum`)?

## Deep background

I am trying to monitor the state of physical hardware from multiple instances of my service deployed via nomad to AWS.
I'm using a custom metric gauge to hold the last-read count for the unique states which I produce with a complete scan every 5 minutes:

```
myservice.valves.latest{site in ('a', 'b', 'c'), room in ('aa', ..., 'cc'), state in ('on', 'off')}
```

Since this is running from within my service, it also has many more tags: each `host`, my individual `erlang_node_names`, other similar cruft. None of them are "stable" (they're things like ip addresses, specific image names, etc).

As a result, if I want to get the count of open valves in a site (a `sum:` aggregation by site and state, discarding `room`) my current attempts in datadog also sum across `host`, and result in the wrong math.

(I know that I should run this export exactly once, instead of exporting too much and then trying to trim it down later. But I have the constraints that I have :-D ).

I am used to systems where I can just stack the aggregations against each other, so that I could first `max by site, room, state` and then follow that with a `sum by site, state`. Does datadog support anything like this?

(The actual ideal wouldn't be to take the `max`; it would actually be to reduce the space on `latest` (!) since that matches the actual semantics of what I'm after. But you see the idea and I don't want to get too side-tracked!)

I have a hack for any dashboards, where I make `erlang_node_name` a parameter the user can choose; in that way, it'll be fairly stable and, should it ever change, they'll be able to fix it with a click.
But that won't work at all for monitors & alerts, so I would like a more stable solution!